# How to root Samsung Young S6312?

Tags: rooting, 4.1-jelly-bean

I tried multiple ways to root my Samsung Galaxy Young S6312, but it still remains unrooted.

I want to know if there are any ways to at least get the "Move to SD Card" option. My main motive for rooting my device is to move my apps to SD card.
I tried the following:

1. Kingo Android Root
2. Kingo Android Root for Windows
3. App2SD (doesn't show move to SD option)
4. Some free apps

Comment: Have you tried using [framaroot](http://androidxda.com/root-samsung-galaxy-young-gt-6312)?

Comment: yes it too doesn't work...it just shuts down without even notifying...after a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try Root Genius for PC.

Connect your Device with PC and enable USB Debugging.

Open Root Genius tools and Start Root.

It will take time to root but at last your device will be rooted and you will  see kinguser app will be installed on your device.

For Download : http://www.shuame.com/en/root/